# Compute a self-referencing variable in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to create a variable in a data frame that will reference the previous row (within that variable being created) to derive a value. I'm relatively new to R, and I'm coming from excel where this type of self-reference and iteratively update feature was pretty straight forward.

```
mydata <- data.frame(trial = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
fixation=c("","","aoi1","aoi1","","aoi3","aoi3","","",""),
trial.marker=c("","","","","","","",1,"",""))
mydata

trial fixation trial.marker
1                      
1                      
1     aoi1             
1     aoi1             
1                      
1     aoi3             
1     aoi3             
1                     1
2                      
2
```

Detailed background: This is a sample from a much larger dataset I have of eye tracking data. Each row represents an observation that's recorded every ~13 ms. The fixation variable indicates where on the screen the subject was looking at that point in the trial. My objective (right now) is to compute a first fixation indication for each trial (what did the subject first fixate in each trial). My approach is to first compute a trial marker to mark the end of each trial, then compute a first fixation variable that will scan the fixation variable for the first "hit" of either "aoi1" or "aoi3, and then retain that information all the way down until it hits the end of the trial (trial marker). I'll then index the data frame by this trial marker, pulling out a one row summary for each trial. I need to code a variety of these types of variables, and the best way I know how to do it is by computing these types of self-referencing variables.

Short background: I need to compute a variable that will detect the first observation in the fixation variable per trial containing either "aoi1" or "aoi3", and record this information on the same row as the 1 values in the trial.marker variable.

I used the shift() function to compute the trial.marker, but this doesn't work appropriately when referencing a previous row of the same variable. The only way I've gotten it to work is with a dreaded for loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(mydata)){

if(i == 1){mydata$first.fixation[i]<- ""}

else if (mydata$trial.marker[i-1]==1){mydata$first.fixation[i]<-""}

else if (mydata$first.fixation[i-1] == ""){

  if(mydata$fixation[i] == "aoi1"){mydata$first.fixation[i] <- "aoi1"}
  else if (mydata$fixation[i] == "aoi3"){mydata$first.fixation[i] <- "aoi3"}
  else mydata$first.fixation[i] <- ""  
  }
 else mydata$first.fixation[i] <- mydata$first.fixation[i-1]
}

mydata

trial fixation trial.marker first.fixation
  1                                     
  1                                     
  1     aoi1                        aoi1
  1     aoi1                        aoi1
  1                                 aoi1
  1     aoi3                        aoi1
  1     aoi3                        aoi1
  1                     1           aoi1
  2                                     
  2
```

The dataset I'm running this on has 1.2 million rows and running this took ~5 hours, so I'm hoping there's a more computationally efficient way to approach it.

Sorry if my R language is weird and/or my post formatting is horrible. It's my first stack overflow post =) Hopefully things are clear enough that you can understand what I'm trying to do here. Because I'm new to R I'm sure there could also be a totally different approach to this that just isn't coming to my mind.. but who knows.

Comment: Dave, the "dread" in the for loop mostly a thing of the past. However, if your code "grows" a vector or other object in a for loop, then expect a significant loss in efficiency. In all programming languages, especially R, create your storage object before the loop. (eg, numeric vector: `numeric(length=MyLength)` or numeric matrix `matrix(0, myRows, myCols)`). If you are only modifying an object, this will be less of a concern. That said, your use of the for loop is can greatly improved through other routes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my shot at it.  Note I am no expert at R (more just using this as a learning exercise) so I am hoping someone else chimes in or at least critiques my code.

I added a couple more lines to your data for a check I was doing.  It still loops but this time just over the number of trials which should be faster.

Ideally you avoid loops in R since vectorized operations are almost always faster.

```
mydata <- data.frame(trial = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
                     fixation=c("","","aoi1","aoi1","","aoi3","aoi3","","aoi3",""),
                     trial.marker=c("","","","","","","",1,"",""))
mydata
#structure shows it produces factored data (which I don't know enough about to like)
str(mydata)

#To avoid factors use stringsAsFactors = FALSE, also added blank column for first.fixation
mydata <- data.frame(trial = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3),
                     fixation=c("","","aoi1","aoi1","","aoi3","aoi3","","","","aoi3",""),
                     trial.marker=c("","","","","","","",1,"",2,"",""),
                     first.fixation="",
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
mydata
str(mydata)


trials<-unique(mydata$trial)

#which returns the indices that match the criteria, function not used for anything just for demonstration
which(mydata$fixation!="" & mydata$trial==1)

#loop through trials
for (i in 1:length(trials)){
  trial<-trials[i]
  #If there are no fixation it would error out so if statement
  if(length(which(mydata$fixation!="" & mydata$trial==trial))>0){
    #Find the last row with the given trial number
    rowmax <- max(which(mydata$trial==trial))
    #Find the first row with given trial number and fixation
    rowmin <- min(which(mydata$fixation!="" & mydata$trial==trial))
    #fill the data in
    mydata$first.fixation[rowmin:rowmax] = mydata$fixation[rowmin]
  }
}
mydata
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it with `data.table`, which usually gives very good performance. Though I have not run a benchmark for volume. This would be the solution.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(mydata)
f <- function(fixation) {
  if (length(which(fixation != "")) == 0) {
    return(rep("", length(fixation)))
  }
  min_informed <- min(which(fixation != ""))
  return(c(rep("", min_informed-1), rep(fixation[min_informed], length(fixation)-min_informed+1)))
}
dt[, fist.fixation:=f(fixation), by=list(trial)]
```

and the output

```
    trial fixation trial.marker fist.fixation
 1:     1                                    
 2:     1                                    
 3:     1     aoi1                       aoi1
 4:     1     aoi1                       aoi1
 5:     1                                aoi1
 6:     1     aoi3                       aoi1
 7:     1     aoi3                       aoi1
 8:     1                     1          aoi1
 9:     2                                    
10:     2                     2              
11:     3     aoi3                       aoi3
12:     3                                aoi3
```

Guessing that you are not familiar to `data.table`, some explanation of the code: in `dt[, fist.fixation:=f(fixation), by=list(trial)]`, 1st argument is the query, in this case all elements, second argument is creating the new column `first.fixation` from the result of the function `f`, and the 3rd argument is grouping by trial => thus the function `f` receives a vector with all the fixations for each trial. Once you have that vector, in the function `f`, it's easy to know which is the first one informed, and so on.

If you decide to check it for your big data.frame, it would be good if you posted the time you get. I think it should take in the order of minutes (maybe quite a few minutes though).

Hope it helps anyway.

Comment: I've just run into data.table recently when I discovered shift(). It seems like there's a lot of potential above and beyond that of data.frame, so I'll definitely learn how to use it when I get a chance.

Comment: Hi. In my experience (which is not so huge honestly), most of the times when I face a somewhat complex transformation like yours I try to make it with functions like `aggregate` and others of `plyr` etc, I end up using `data.table` and the final code I get is clearer and faster -although it is true that the library more difficult to learn. In your case, if the solution you've posted takes seconds, I don't think `data.table` is going to beat that, thus no point on investigating further. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

So I'm pretty sure I solved this problem using a different method. Typing my question made it clear to me that I'm looking for a trial summary and so I did the following:

```
first.match <- function(x,y){
 match.list <- sort(match(x,y),decreasing=FALSE)
 y[match.list[1]]  
}

ff.data <-aggregate(x=exp2data$aoifixation,
by=list(exp2data$subject,exp2data$trial),
FUN=function(x) first.match(c("AOI1","AOI3"),x))
```

This gave me first fixation summarized for each trial (by each subject; not shown in the example above, however). Then I used the trial marker technique to index down the original dataset, and just added the first fixation vector from aggregate onto the trimmed down dataset.

```
ff.data <- ff.data[order(ff.data$Group.1,ff.data$Group.2),]
exp2data.trial <- exp2data[exp2data$trialmarker==1,]
exp2data.trial$ff <- ff.data[,3]
```

I'm still triple checking to make sure it coded correctly, but it appears to be good. The best part is it ran in a few seconds! I haven't tried yet, but I think I'll be able to get all the weird eye tracking variables that I'll need out of the within trial data by just modifying the custom function in aggregate.